# How to select and copy data up to the searched value?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone please help me out, Im getting a little bit desperate

I want to search for data and then select and copy every-row up to the searched point, however I wasnt able to do this all I can do is to copy the row that includes the searched data

[image: What i want to achieve]

```
Sub Prehled()

    Dim datarng As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim VysledekHledani As Long
    Dim Obdobi As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Obdobi = Sheets("IN7").Range("Kvartal").Value
    
    Sheets("PomocnyList_3").Select
    Sheets("PomocnyList_3").AutoFilterMode = False
    
    lr = Sheets("PomocnyList_3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set datarng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AZ$" & lr)
    
    If Obdobi <> "" Then
        If en_likematch = True Then
            datarng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & Obdobi & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Else
            datarng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Obdobi
        End If
    End If
    
    VysledekHledani = Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    
    If VysledekHledani > 1 Then
        
        Sheets("K_report").Select
        Cells.Range("B25").Value = "Test?"
         
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End If
    
    If VysledekHledani > 1 Then
        Sheets("PomocnyList_3").Select
        Range("A2:AZ99").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        Selection.Copy
     
        Sheets("K_report").Select
        
        Range("E25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
              
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Will there only be one visible row after the filtering?

Comment: "every row up to the searched point" meaning you want row 2 to row where the value is found?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes at this moment there is only one row (with searched result) visible - I have no idea how else to code this

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes - in my example in the picture I was searching for 2016/Q4 so I want to copy everything up to ROW5 - basically I will always want to copy everything starting row1 and last row copied will be the row with searched value

Comment: Why not just search for Obdobi in the A column then with a simple Match (or for loop if you don't want to use excel formulas) and then use the `Range("A1:A" & foundRow).Entirerow.Copy`? I'm not that familiar working without "copy paste/copy destination:" yet so apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Application.Match()`:

```vb
Sub Prehled()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, wsRpt As Worksheet
    Dim Obdobi As String, wc As String, m
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'best to be specific...
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("PomocnyList_3")
    Set wsRpt = wb.Worksheets("K_report")
    
    wsSrc.AutoFilterMode = False
    wc = IIf(en_likematch, "*", "") 'need wildcards?
    
    Obdobi = wb.Worksheets("IN7").Range("Kvartal").Value
    If Len(Obdobi) = 0 Then 'anything to search for?
        MsgBox "No search term entered", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'see if there's a match in ColA
    m = Application.Match(wc & Obdobi & wc, wsSrc.Columns("A"), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then 'if not an error then we got a match
        With wsSrc.Range("A2:AZ" & m)
            wb.Worksheets("K_report").Range("E25").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your time and effort! I have written something similiar, based on your previous input (had no idea that something like App.Match is existing, have been VBA "coder" for 14 days =D) - yours version seems to be working better so I'm gonna use it for now. Once again, thank you and have a great day!